# Paramiko BindAddress option

Tags: python, sockets, ssh, paramiko

I am trying to use paramiko to connect to a remote host.  However, in order to connect, I need to specify a bind address, which you can do with OpenSSH via:

```
ssh -o BindAddress=x.x.x.x user@host
```

I've been searching high and low for an equivalent option in the paramiko SSHClient docs, but I can't seem to find it.  It seems like this would be a standard option to have.  Can someone point me in the right direction?  Do I need to create a separate socket connection and use that?

Answer (score 1):

From `ssh_config` manual:

> BindAddress
>                Use the specified address on the local machine as **the source address of the connection**.

You might provide a socket to client's connect function, so you might bind the source address in the socket.

Example:

```
import socket
import paramiko

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

sock.bind(('192.168.223.21', 0))           # set source address
sock.connect(('192.168.223.23', 22))       # connect to the destination address

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect('192.168.223.23', 
               username=username, 
               password=password, 
               sock=sock)                  # pass socket to Paramiko
```

Documentation: http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.4/api/client.html).

> connect(hostname, port=22, username=None, password=None, pkey=None,
>   key_filename=None, timeout=None, allow_agent=True, look_for_keys=True,
>   compress=False, **sock=None**, gss_auth=False, gss_kex=False,
>   gss_deleg_creds=True, gss_host=None, banner_timeout=None,
>   auth_timeout=None, gss_trust_dns=True, passphrase=None)
>
> **sock (socket)** – an open socket or socket-like object (such as a
>   Channel) to use for communication to the target host

Comment: This worked for me.
I'm using `sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BINDTODEVICE, bind_to_interface.encode('utf-8'))` to bind to interface rather than IP.
However, a significant thing to note is that the timeout= parameter passed to client.connect() needs to be set on the socket (`sock.settimeout(timeout)`) before calling sock.connect(), if you need a timeout on the connection attempt.